Update .NET from 6 to 8 - Detected package downgrade: Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version
I'm trying to upgrade several packages in my project after changing the target framework from .NET 6 to 8, but I don't know how to solve this error. When I'm trying to update the package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager from 6.0 to 8.0, I get this error:
Warning As Error: Detected package downgrade: YamlDotNet from 15.1.2 to 11.2.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.

But when I try to update YamlDotNet from 11.2.1 to 15.1.2, I get this error:
Warning As Error: Detected package downgrade: System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager from 8.0.0 to 6.0.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.

I get a similar behaviour from other packages too. So each package prevents the other from being upgraded? How do I solve this?

Can you please provide a [mre]? Also why exactly do you need System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager (from the description - "This package exists only to support migrating existing .NET Framework code that already uses System.Configuration.")?

This indicates that you reference old packages that simply isn't necessary, try removing packages and see what happens.

It's the same behaviour for the packages EntityFrameworkCore and EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.

Its a little weird. You may want to try removing some packages first and reinstalling things?

Its always a symptom of you missing the upgrades on all of the dependant projects.

These messages are usually a symptom of you missing the upgrades in some of the dependant projects.
To be safe you should upgrade all of the projects in your solution to .Net 8.0 and also update all of the libraries in all of your projects to the latest version (only build after all of the updates).
If even that doesn't help, delete bin and obj folders in all of your projects and rebuild solution from scratch.
